# Does this equivalence relation characterize continued fractions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, equivalence-relations, continued-fractions

Consider a pair of *integer-valued* sequences $(a(n), b(n))$ such that the continued fraction

$$a(0) + \cfrac{b(1)}{a(1) + \cfrac{b(2)}{a(2) + \cdots}},$$

exists. Given a strictly-nonzero sequence $c(n)$, we have the identity

$$a(0) + \cfrac{b(1)}{a(1) + \cfrac{b(2)}{a(2) + \cdots}}
=
a(0) + \cfrac{c(1) b(1)}{c(1) a(1) + \cfrac{c(1) c(2) b(2)}{c(2) a(2) + \cdots}}.
$$

More explicitly, we replace $a(n)$ with $c(n) a(n)$ for $n \geq 0$ and $b(n)$ with $c(n) c(n - 1) b(n)$ for $n \geq 1$, taking $c(0) = 1$.

Define the relation on pairs of sequences $(a, b) \sim (a', b')$ to mean that there exists such a transforming sequence $c$; namely,
\begin{align*}
    a(n) &= c(n) a'(n), \quad n \geq 0 \\
    b(n) &= c(n - 1) c(n) b'(n), \quad n \geq 1,
\end{align*}
where $c(n) \neq 0$ for $n \geq 1$ and $c(0) = 1$.

If we allow the transforming sequence $c(n)$ to be rational-valued, then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and "generates the same continued fraction" is an invariant under its equivalence classes.

**Is $(a, b) \sim (a', b')$ *equivalent* to "$(a, b)$ and $(a', b')$ generate the same continued fraction"?**

In other words, if $(a, b)$ and $(a', b')$ generate the same continued fraction, does there exist a "transforming sequence" $c(n)$ which takes $(a', b')$ to $(a, b)$?

Comment: What does "generate the same CF" mean? (Convergence to the same value?)

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, I mean that they converge to the same value. The question is whether one sequence be transformed into the other by the above approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample: $$\sqrt{3}-1=\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}=\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$ Here $$\begin{aligned}
a(0)&=0&b(n)&=1&a(2n-1)&=1&a(2n)&=2\\
a'(0)&=0&a'(n)&=1&b'(2n-1)&=2&b'(2n)&=3
\end{aligned}\qquad(n>0)$$ and clearly $\color{blue}{(a,b)\nsim(a',b')}$, since otherwise we would have $c(n)=a(n)/a'(n)=a(n)$ for $n>0$, hence $c(n-1)c(n)=2$ for $n>1$, hence $b(n)/b'(n)=2$ for $n>1$, which is a contradiction.